# Is hashdeep deprecated?

Tags: windows, linux

The other day corporate or the vendor used their cloud deployment tool to replace some of our DLLs, and it got me wondering; does anyone still use hashdeep when they initially roll out a server or important workstation, store the hashes to immutable media and then periodically check the hashes to make sure they still match?

Of course this wouldn't apply to user files or log files.

Probably should apply to config files however, but with care...

Is this method of File Integrity Verification deprecated?

Is it built into other things?  Like in Windows, DISM, sfc, virus scanners or maybe Applocker?